# Vimeo video upload crashing in Swift when upload video to the server

Tags: ios, swift, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-ios

The video actually gets uploaded but in the settings where title and description of video do not get updated at that time where the app crashes.

Here i am attaching screenshot where crashes happening.

[image]

Comment: You!.need!.to!.rethink!.your!.use!.of!.optionals! https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: Okay, @NicolasMiari , but this issue occurring in their official repository so i was little bit confuse :-(

Comment: Hi @VivekGoswami I also faced this issue and this is the bug in VimeoUpload-iOS, You have to use old uploader. Please refer this link. https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload/issues/149

Answer (score 1):

Crash happens because either `uploadTicket`, `video` or `uri` is `nil` .You're using force unwrapping, and that will cause a crash if the value you're unwrapping is `nil`. Try instead

```
if let videoUri = self.uploadTicket?.video?.uri {
    // put rest of the code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, Crash issue solved but process of uploading is endless. @mag_zbc